# Android TexttoSpeech Override other sounds

Tags: android, audio, text-to-speech

I am using Android TTS to speak a text. The speaking is done on a service. I am using   `TTS..speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);` my speak() function is called several times, during intervals. Because it is a service, its possible that other sounds are playing while speak() is called.

I want to know how to 'silence' those other sounds WHILE my text is being spoken.

Answer (score 1):

The term you need to search for is 'audio ducking'. It's not an obvious one, so you can be forgiven for not finding any solutions with other search terms!

Check out the suggested way to handle this [in the tutorial here](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html).

I assume you will want to just lower any other media volume so the speech can be heard = ducking.

[AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK)

Alternatively, you can request that other apps silence any media, until your onUtteranceCompleted is called and you release the audio focus. Beware though, if the other apps aren't handling the loss and gain of focus correctly, their media will not restart and your user will probably be annoyed...